# Outbound message Endpoint URL of the Same sales force org

Tags: community, webservices

I have created rest web service and trying to entered endpoint url to outbound message. How can i do this?

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
 req.setEndpoint('https://imshealth--dev25.cs30.my.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/Account/');
 req.setMethod('GET');
 Http http = new Http();
 HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
 System.assert(false, res.getBody());
```

AFter execution it says:

session expire

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the REST method is in the same org all you need to do is pass in the session ID:

after the set endpoint add...

```
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth '+UserInfo.getSessionId());
```

With that said, since you are in the same org, why not just call the method directly:

```
MyRestClass.MyGetMethod(PARAMS);
```

Comment: the same error i got when i put this endpoint url in outbound message. how can we provide session id there?

Comment: @vikasgupta - That would be a new question. Please post it as a new question and someone will be along to answer